# Maven OWL API Como resolver erro de dependências

Tags: java, maven, owl

Minha pergunta é referente ao Maven. Eu estou trabalhando em um projeto que envolve a biblioteca OWL API e após a tentativa de carregar uma ontologia o projeto retornou um erro que pode ser visto na imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referente a esse erro encontrei o link [OWL API resolução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459428/getting-error-in-executing-owl-api) que recomendava a instalação do Maven.
Até agora não achei como intalar a OWL API pelo maven para resolver esse problema de dependência e gostaria de perguntar se alguém sabe a resposta ou se pelo menos tem alguns links ou videos que eu possa encontrar a resposta.

Windows 10 - Vitor Hugo Maciel dos Santos - Universitário tentando resolver um problema

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o link que você comentou ([OWL API resolução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459428/getting-error-in-executing-owl-api)) você pode adicionar as dependências do owlapi e do owlapi-osgi (essa dependência deve resolver o problema de acordo com o link) no seu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-osgidistribution</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Caso você não queira usar o maven no final da página ele mostra todas as dependências do owlapi e em todas as páginas tem a opção de baixar o JAR.

Comment: Eu achei que o problema era isso sim, porém adicionei a dependência antes de criar o fórum aqui no meu arquivo pom.xml como dizia em um video que vi na internet e mesmo assim não funcionou. Acho que talvez meu pom.xml pode estar errado então vou compartilhar aqui o código dele. [pom.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnkoh6vlemsddav/pom.xml?dl=0)

Comment: @vitorhugomacieldossantos, de acordo com o link que você enviou falta adicionar a dependência para a owlapi-osgi. Eu alterei a minha resposta, dá uma olhada, vê se te ajuda.

Comment: Vlw funcionou agr, obrigado.